# Ldahist(0 function Object not found

Tags: r, lda

I am learning LDA using Wine data.
The dependent variable is called "Type" with 13 predictors.

```
wine.lda<-lda(Type ~., data = wine)
wine.lda$svd
wine.lda.values <- predict(wine.lda)
ldahist(data = wine.lda.values$x[,1], g=Type)
######OUTPUTS#########
> wine.lda<-lda(Type ~., data = wine)
> wine.lda$svd
[1] 28.18958 19.00634
> wine.lda.values <- predict(wine.lda)
> ldahist(data = wine.lda.values$x[,1], g=Type)
Error in ldahist(data = wine.lda.values$x[, 1], g = Type) : 
  object 'Type' not found
```

Everything was just fine. But when I tried to plot histogram. It gave me this error "object not found". I checked my code several times, but i couldnt find the reason.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The message makes me think you should have put quotes around "Type" or perhaps it wanted `wine$Type`.  In R object column names are not objects in their own right.

Comment: you are absolutely right about putting Wine$Type. I am learning LDA using this https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/35817_2552e05f1d4e4db8ba87b334101a43da.html    apparently, it has an error. Thank you so much.

Comment: They probably did the braindead maneuver of using `attach`. This is a good example of why I call it that.